# SQL Where condition a is met and condition b is met No Results

Tags: sql

This is a bit specific so please bear with me...

I want my where statement to give me all the results that meet the following criteria:

```
WHERE
TestCode = A1 
AND
TestResult > 50
AND
TestCode = A2
AND
TestResult > 200
```

In real terms I want a list of all the patients that have both an `A1>50` whilst also having an `A2 > 200`

I can see that this will not work "as is" because I'm giving the clause two sets of greater thans, but however I add brackets to indicate what I want, it returns no data.

Original (not working) query

```
      AND 
(SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestCode_DR  =  'A0165'  AND  SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestData  >  '35')
  AND  
(SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestCode_DR  =  'A0155'  AND  SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestData  >  '25')
)
```

Working Code

```
      AND 
((SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestCode_DR  =  'A0165'  AND  SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestData  >  '35') OR (SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestCode_DR  =  'A0155'  AND  SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestData  >  '25'))
  AND  
((SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestCode_DR  =  'A0155'  AND  SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestData  >  '25') OR (SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestCode_DR  =  'A0165'  AND  SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestData  >  '35'))
```

Sorry about the formatting...

Comment: what rdbms? Also, can you provide the table structure?

Comment: Please add some sample data of your tables ;).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the table structure.  I suspect I'm going to get in Stack-Trouble for this, but this is actually a business objects question, I just thought I'd get better advice from this group.  As for sample data, the patient has a sample taken, this is analysed for test A1 and test B1 and both results are returned against that patient number.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: `TestCode` cannot, simultaneously, be equal to both `A1` and `A2`. So the reason this doesn't work has nothing to do with "two sets of greater thans". Please add some sample data and expected results so that we can try to see what you're asking.

Comment: @Paul, for future readers, the correct answers to your question should be marked - just saying, because many wont bother reading all the comments. Regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Were you looking to do something like this?

```
 WHERE ((TestCode = A1) AND (TestResult > 50)) OR ((TestCode = A2) AND (TestResult > 200))
```

It looks like your testing for `WHEN TestCode = 'A1'` `AND` `WHEN TestCode = 'A2'` Which would be impossible for them to equal both at the same time, returning empty.

Comment: Thanks Ejesalva, I see what you're doing there and I'll try to recreate it.  I will obviously mark as solved once I've successfully done it.

Comment: @Paul, no problem. As some of the guys mentioned above, try to put some sample output that your trying to get. Everyone here is trying to help!

Comment: I can't believe how helpful you guys have been (I'm used to BO support!).  I've extended Ejesalva's suggestion and it worked.  I'll edit the original bit with my before and after for anyone else that looks for this solution.  Many thanks EVERYONE

Comment: @Paul . . . I'm curious why you accepted this answer.  This gives all patients who passed either test, but not necessarily both.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I changed Ejesalva's "OR" to an "AND"

Comment: @Paul . . . Then the code should return nothing, because `TestCode` cannot be both `A1` and `A2`.  I'm pretty sure several of the other answers do provide a correct answer to your question.

Comment: @Gordon, I assumed that he was looking for the `OR` statement judging by his code. It didn't make sense for the variable to equal `'A1'` `AND` `'A2'`.

Comment: @Ejesalva . . . That is possible, and this is a fine answer for that question.  However, the question does clearly say: "In real terms I want a list of all the patients that have both an A1>50 whilst also having an A2 > 200".

Comment: @Gordon The key here is that Ejesalva put me on the path to my cumbersome solution.  The intersect and "having" "sum" solutions are the things I will look into as they are much better than what I cobbled together.

Comment: @Gordon, I see where your coming from, your right. Its important to make sure of everything before posting answers. I should have been more thorough when reading.

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax you're after is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM    your_table AS A
WHERE   EXISTS (
            SELECT TOP 1 1 
            FROM    your_table AS A1_50
            WHERE   A1_50.ID = A.ID
                AND A1_50.TestCode = 'A1'
                AND A1_50.TestResult > 50)
    AND EXISTS (
            SELECT TOP 1 1 
            FROM    your_table AS A2_200
            WHERE   A2_200.ID = A.ID
                AND A2_200.TestCode = 'A2'
                AND A2_200.TestResult > 200)
```

Just replace your_table with the table you're querying and ID with the patient_id column you're checking to have the scores > 50 / 200

EDIT:
You can also use INTERSECT:

```
SELECT  PatientID 
FROM    your_table 
WHERE   TestCode = 'A1'
    AND TestResult > 50
INTERSECT 
SELECT  PatientID 
FROM    your_table 
WHERE   TestCode = 'A2'
    AND TestResult > 200
```

Comment: I'll go and look at intersect now.  Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this (guessing on the table and field names):

```
SELECT * from Patients p1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Patients p2 
              WHERE p1.ID = p2.ID
                 AND p2.TestCode = A1 AND p2.TestResult > 50)  
  AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Patients p2 
              WHERE p1.ID = p2.ID
              AND p2.TestCode = A2 AND p2.TestResult > 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work on almost every rdbms:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t1
WHERE TestCode = 'A1' AND TestResult > 50
AND EXISTS(
   SELECT 1
   FROM YourTable t2 
   WHERE t2.patientId = t1.PatientId
   AND TestCode = 'A2' AND TestResult > 200
)
```

Comment: Another good approach.  Who knew there were so many ways of achieving my objective.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is no row will both have TestCode = A1 and TestCode = A2. You can either change you conditional to

`WHERE
(TestCode = A1 AND TestResult > 50)
OR
(TestCode = A2 AND TestResult > 200)`

or use UNION like this:

`SELECT * 
FROM foo
WHERE
TestCode = 'A1'
AND 
TestResult > 50
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM foo
WHERE
TestCode = 'A2'
AND 
TestResult > 50`

Comment: Oh I see.  That's an interesting way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your table looks something like this:

```
TestCode    TestResult   PersonId
A1           30           1
A1           60           2
A1           90           3
A2           60           3
A2           90           1
A2          120           2
```

Then you can do this:

```
SELECT t1.PersonId 
FROM TestData t1
INNER JOIN TestData t2 on t1.PersonId = t2.PersonId
WHERE t1.TestCode = 'A1' AND t2.TestCode = 'A2'
AND t1.TestResult > 50
AND t2.TestResult > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `join` to the table that has `TestCode` twice, once for the `A1` test, and once for the `A2` test.  Then your `where` clause could be:

```
WHERE a1.TestResult > 50 AND a2.TestResult > 200
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want patients who passed *both* tests, then I suggest `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
select PatientId
from . ..
group by PatientId
having sum(case when SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestCode_DR = 'A0165'  AND  
                     SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestData  >  '35'
                then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestCode_DR = 'A0155'  AND
                      SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSetData.VISTD_TestData  >  '25'
                then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each `sum()` in the `having` clauses counts the number of records where the condition is true.  The `> 0` ensures that there is at least one such record.

I like this approach because it is flexible -- you can readily add another test, or test for 2 out of three tests, for instance.

Comment: This I like a lot.  The flexability is a huge bonus in my work.  Thanks Gordon.